# How do I instantiate the Profile from an ashx file?

Tags: asp.net, httphandler, ashx, profile-provider

I recently switched some AJAX queries to use ashx files instead of aspx, having discovered that `Response.End` is no longer in vogue.  In the case I'm looking at now, the submission of a purchase order is handled by the ashx.  The user clicks the Submit button on the PO and the ashx file records the time and the user in a database table.  An object with the current user's data (including their primary key) is stored in the Session and is recorded there by a custom Profile Provider.  I have added `IReadOnlySessionState` in order to be able to access the Session, but it appears that, unless another .net page has been accessed, the Profile Provider doesn't run and the Session has no values.  (verified by stepping through the code.)

I tried `IRequiresSessionState`, but the same results.

I'm assuming that the `System.Web.UI.Page` HttpHandler instantiates the custom Profile if it hasn't been already and that I'll need to add that to my custom HttpHandler.

I looked briefly at HttpModules, but I don't think that's what I want because they load for each request.

Comment: Are you saying you're using a custom Profile Provider? Does that provider place data into Session?! That seems like a rube-goldberg machine.

Comment: @JJS - yes and yes.  You say that like Rube Goldberg machines aren't cool, lol.  I wrote it maybe 10 years ago during a port from a classic asp site.  I suspect I did it that way because Profile seemed the place to put that information and the asp application used Session to store profile information.  In retrospect, I probably should have used the Profile custom properties or maybe as a function on the custom Profile that accessed the Session.  Either of which would solve the problem of instantiating the Profile object prior to accessing the Session.

Comment: Rube Goldberg machines ARE very cool, when they work, but they're a pain to maintain. If we knew today when we knew 10 years ago, we'd do it differently. Hindsight is 20/20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the value of `HttpContext.Current.Profile`? The Profile property is populated during the AcquireRequestState stage of the Request lifecycle by the built in HttpModule `ProfileModule`.

There is great info here http://odetocode.com/articles/440.aspx on how the internals work.

Comment: Looks like I get an object of type ProfileCommon.  But then the error disappears, which probably means that it's being instantiated when it's accessed.  I'll check out the article.

Comment: How were you accessing profile before? and Yes, it is instantiated when accessed http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpContext.cs,bba8c379705d1d18

Comment: I was calling a function that accessed the Session values (which should have been populated by the custom Profile).  It's possible my code accessed the Profile on aspx pages before anything else though.  I'll run a test.

Comment: ok, looks like the Profile is not instantiated by default on a default `System.Web.UI.Page`.  My derived Page class prints out the user's name in the header, so it would always have been available.  Thanks for those great resource links.

Comment: glad I could be of help.